# Using SignalR, how do I send a dictionary (associative array) to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, signalr

dictionary isn't serializeable, and therefore can't be sent to my clients JavaScript code via SignalR as a Javascript (pseudo) associative array...

in .net, my complex type is:

```
public class MyClass {
   public [primitive] whatever {get;set;}
   ...
   public Dictionary<string, string> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

and in Javascript, I'd like to be able to reference the data like this:

```
data.Properties["key"]
```

Update:

I'm trying to serialize to and from a string first because I route the instance through SQL Service Broker.  On this line:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
```

Where T is typeof MyClass

> There was an error reflecting type [MyClass]
>
> Cannot serialize member [MyClass].Properties of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], because it implements IDictionary.

I feel like I'm about to answer my own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
```

to:

```
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
```

(and dealt with some namespace issues...)

Answer (score 2):

SignalR uses Json.NET which is definitely able to to serialize a `Dictionary<string, string>`. You should be able to access the dictionary from JS code in the exact manner you suggest in your question.

Have you tried sending an instance of your `MyClass` using SignalR? If so, how does it fail?

Comment: My apologies @halter73, I'm serializing to a and from a string first... (I'm bouncing the object instance through SQL Service Broker).  I've updated the question.